# R dynamic sql query using RODBC and export to .csv

Tags: sql, r, for-loop, wait, rodbc

If I run the following code in R studio then it works but I have set sys.sleep.  I have a large batch of queries to run and I don't know how long each will take.  If I exclude the sys.sleep then the exports are blank as the export is run before the query is complete.  Is there a way of getting R to wait until the query is complete?

```
#setup
  #install.packages("stringr", dependencies=TRUE)
  require(stringr)
  library(RODBC)    

#odbc connection
  db <- odbcDriverConnect("dsn=DW Master;uid=username;pwd=password;")   

#sql to be run
  qstr <- "select top 10 * from prod"

#variable
  weeknum<-c('201401','201402','201403')

for (i in weeknum ) 
  {
  data <- sqlQuery(db, qstr, believeNRows = FALSE)
  Sys.sleep(10)
  filename<-paste("data_", str_trim(i), ".csv")
  filename
  write.csv(data, file = filename)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425100/rodbc-queries-returning-zero-rows), try adding the `rows_at_time` argument:

```
data <- sqlQuery(db, qstr, believeNRows = FALSE, rows_at_time = 1)
```

Alternatively you can break up the two processes:

```
# QUERIES TO DATA FRAMES
weeknum<-c('201401','201402','201403')
for (i in weeknum ) {
  data <- sqlQuery(db, qstr, believeNRows = FALSE, rows_at_time = 1)
  assign(paste("data",i,sep=""),data)   
}

# DATA FRAMES TO CSV FILES
dfList <- c('data201401','data201402','data201403')
for (n in dfList) {
  df<-get(n)
  filename<-paste(n, ".csv", sep="")
  write.csv(df, file = filename)
}
```