# RODBC returning 0 rows even though there are many rows

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I have this database on SQL Server. When I run the following query:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDateField <= '2014-12-31'`

I get 51618 rows.

But when I run the exact same query from R, using RODBC, I get "<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)".

Now let's say I change the date:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDateField <= '2010-01-01'`

Then I get the exact same results both on SQL Server directly and on R (!?).

I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425100/rodbc-queries-returning-zero-rows) and so I tried adding `believeNRows = FALSE` and `rows_at_time = 1` to my `odbcDriverConnect` statement. But that didn't change anything.

So, what could possibly be going on here? I've been at this for almost 24 hours now and I'm completely out of ideas.

Client: CentOS 7.1.1503, R 3.2.1, RODBC 1.3-12

Server: Windows Server 2012, SQL Server 2014

Comment: Just to try stuff... Can you make a view on the server that is defined by your desired query and then run `select * from your_view` in R?  Another thing to do would be to keep moving your `2010-01-01` closer to `2014-12-31` to see where the breakdown occurs.

Comment: Ha! That did it. I kept moving the date closer and closer to 2014-12-31, as you suggested, and so I found out that the problem is in the formatting: somehow the dates are interpreted as yyyy-dd-mm when SQL Server receives the query from RODBC. Many thanks! Now on to figuring out why this is happening.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

Comment: Solved! If you want to turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it, so you get proper credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you can do is to change the working date incrementally until you discover a pattern that causes the query to fail.  Perhaps (for future readers) the problem is that SQL Server is expecting a format other than the standard.  If that's the case then a query for the first day of the first month would (by coincidence only) return the proper result.  You can use [set dateformat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) to get SQL Server to accept the format you need.